# How to set State from an Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

Hello guys I have a question regarding Arrays in React Native and setting the State.

Lets say I have some States setup that look like this:

```
D00: 0,
D01: 0,
D02: 0,
D03: 0,
D04: 0,
D05: 0,
D06: 0,

D10: 0,
D11: 0,
D12: 0,
D13: 0,
D14: 0,
D15: 0,
D16: 0,

D20: 0,
D21: 0,
D22: 0,
D23: 0,
D24: 0,
D25: 0,
D26: 0,

D30: 0,
D31: 0,
D32: 0,
D33: 0,
D34: 0,
D35: 0,
D36: 0,

D40: 0,
D41: 0,
D42: 0,
D43: 0,
D44: 0,
D45: 0,
D46: 0,

D50: 0,
D51: 0,
D52: 0,
D53: 0,
D54: 0,
D55: 0,
D56: 0,
```

I have like 4 State setups like this and also 4 Arrays with the Data that has to be set to the States.

The Arrays look like this:

```
06DSo.,10DMo.,11DDi.,12DMi.,13DDo.,14DFr.,15DSa.,16DSo.,20DMo.,21DDi.,22DMi.,23DDo.,24DFr.,25DSa.,26DSo.,30DMo.,31DDi.,32DMi.,33DDo.,34DFr.,35DSa.,36DSo.,40DMo.,41DDi.,42DMi.,43DDo.,44DFr.,45DSa.,46DSo.,50DMo.,51DDi.
```

Now my Question is how can I set the values from the Array to the state that they need to be in?

For example my Array starts with **"06D"** and the Value that is important would be **"So."** in this case. So I would need to set the State from **"d06"** to **"So."**

Now as you can see it does not always start on **"d00"** and also does not end on **"d56"**. I need to set the State dynamically and only set the state of the values that occur in my Array.

Is there a way to do this? So only set the states where the Array actually has the Value and omit the rest?

What I have tried is to map the values but for that I have to do some transformation on the element that gets mapped:

```
  inputControllsSetState = () => {
    this.state.arrayD.map((x) => {
      var _stateX = x[2] + x[0] + x[1];
      var _valX = x[3] + x[4] + x[5];
      console.log("State: " + _stateX + " || value: " + _valX);
     
      // this.setState({
      //   _stateX: _valX 
      // })
    
    })
     

 }
```

This is the console log I am getting which has the correct name but the state cant be set that way since _stateX is no state that is declared.

```
State: D06 || value: So.
State: D10 || value: Mo.
State: D11 || value: Di.
State: D12 || value: Mi.
State: D13 || value: Do.
State: D14 || value: Fr.
State: D15 || value: Sa.
State: D16 || value: So.
State: D20 || value: Mo.
State: D21 || value: Di.
State: D22 || value: Mi.
State: D23 || value: Do.
State: D24 || value: Fr.
State: D25 || value: Sa.
State: D26 || value: So.
State: D30 || value: Mo.
State: D31 || value: Di.
State: D32 || value: Mi.
State: D33 || value: Do.
State: D34 || value: Fr.
State: D35 || value: Sa.
State: D36 || value: So.
State: D40 || value: Mo.
State: D41 || value: Di.
State: D42 || value: Mi.
State: D43 || value: Do.
State: D44 || value: Fr.
State: D45 || value: Sa.
State: D46 || value: So.
State: D50 || value: Mo.
State: D51 || value: Di.
State: D06 || value: So.
State: D10 || value: Mo.
State: D11 || value: Di.
State: D12 || value: Mi.
State: D13 || value: Do.
State: D14 || value: Fr.
State: D15 || value: Sa.
State: D16 || value: So.
State: D20 || value: Mo.
State: D21 || value: Di.
State: D22 || value: Mi.
State: D23 || value: Do.
State: D24 || value: Fr.
State: D25 || value: Sa.
State: D26 || value: So.
State: D30 || value: Mo.
State: D31 || value: Di.
State: D32 || value: Mi.
State: D33 || value: Do.
State: D34 || value: Fr.
State: D35 || value: Sa.
State: D36 || value: So.
State: D40 || value: Mo.
State: D41 || value: Di.
State: D42 || value: Mi.
State: D43 || value: Do.
State: D44 || value: Fr.
State: D45 || value: Sa.
State: D46 || value: So.
State: D50 || value: Mo.
State: D51 || value: Di.
```

Any help would be appreciated - Faded.

Comment: You are on the good way! Instead of instanciating a new variable inside your map, you should use the setState hook to modify a state value.

Comment: you could also use the previousState argument of setState function to utilize variables from previous state and only update the ones that have changed.
```this.setState((prevState) => { ...prevState, [_stateX]: _valX })```

Comment: @BenjaminRio I am using the class based component so that would not work I guess.

Comment: @sushrut619 That actually seems to work - thanks dude!